# Quick way to edit a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with around 4 millions rows.

```
A B C
1 2 '2019-12-30'
3 4 '03/04/2020'
```

Column C contains date in string format and has two type of variations. I am trying to normalize this column so the time format are the same. Right now I am doing the following.

```
def fixDate(x):
    if '/' in x:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')

df['C'] = df['C'].apply(fixDate)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do? This feels rather clunky and slow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.C.str.strip("'"),dayfirst=True)
Out[238]: 
0   2019-12-30
1   2020-04-03
Name: C, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```